# Two stored procedures in SQL Server with same name

Tags: sql-server

We have two stored procedures inMS SQL Server 2008 R2 with the same name (`spGetGenesysVSHRMisMatch`). One is in the master database and the other in a user database. There is a job that calls the stored procedure without using the database name or schema. The stored procedure that is executed is the one on the user database, not master.

How is this possible?

Comment: How did you create the Job?  How are you executing the job?

Comment: somewhere along the line you're telling the job what database to use

Comment: Have you set the database to use within the job step, rather than within the TSQL (check with `SELECT database_name, step_name, job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps`)

Comment: check the connection string that initialises the command. if the "job" is coming from an external application there may well be an "initial catalog" specified in the string

Comment: @Rich That shouldn't be relevant, jobs are stored and invoked in MSDB, and are blind to who or what invoked them. So  executing `USE msdb; EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = N'Some Job';`, would be no different to `USE SomeDB; EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = N'Some Job';`

Comment: I did not create the job, I inherited it. It was created on the SQL server in the Jobs area. It runs automatically everyday at 5:00 am. The first line of the sproc is a USE statement then a GO. The job does not come from an external app, it runs on SQL Server.

Comment: *"The first line of the sproc is a USE statement then a GO"*, do you mean the transact SQL in the job step rather than the proc? `GO` is a batch separator and not valid in a stored procedure. Can you show the results of the following statement please? - `SELECT database_name, step_name, job_id, command FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps WHERE command LIKE '%spGetGenesysVSHRMisMatch%'`

Comment: What is the IDENTITY(user) of the executor of the job?  And then, what is the default database of this IDENTITY(user)?